# What Common Lisp environment to use on Mac?

Tags: macos, emacs, common-lisp

What Common Lisp environment are you people using? I'm just starting with the book Practical Common Lisp of Peter Seibel (it's also free to read online at http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) and in the book Lisp in a Box (http://common-lisp.net/project/lispbox/) is recommended.

However, it hasn't been updated since 2011 and the Emacs version distributed is rather old (23.2.1). So I updated the Emacs version to 24.3.1 with the distribution provided at http://emacsformacosx.com. This one has a better Mac OS X integration.

To update the Emacs version follow these steps:

1. Download and install *lispbox 0.7*
2. Download Emacs for *Mac OSX 24.3.1*
3. In lispbox-0.7 I rename **Emacs.app** to **Emacs.old.app**
4. Copy **Emacs.app** from the *Emacs for Mac OS X* distribution to **lispbox-0.7/**
5. Copy **Emacs.app.old/MacOSX/lispbox.sh** to **Emacs.app/MacOSX** *Tip: if you are using Finder, select 'Show package contents'*
6. Copy **Emacs.old.app/Resources/site-lisp/lispbox.el** to **Emacs.app/Resources/site-lisp**
   7.Then edit **Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/lispbox.sh** as shown below

lispbox.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "${0:0:2}" = "./" ]; then
    export LISPBOX_HOME=`pwd`/../../..
else
    export LISPBOX_HOME=`dirname $0`/../../..
fi
export SBCL_HOME=${LISPBOX_HOME}/sbcl-1.0.42/lib/sbcl
#exec ${LISPBOX_HOME}/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --no-init-file --no-site-file --eval='(progn (load "lispbox") (slime))'
exec ${LISPBOX_HOME}/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-10.7 --no-site-file --eval='(progn (load "lispbox") (slime))'
```

You then can start the Emacs with the Lisp environment by executing lispbox.sh

Note that i changed the editor and I removed the *--no-init-file* option to be sure ~/.emacs is being read. To still be able to use the with *Lisp in a Box*-provided Emacs version you can should edit the *Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/lispbox.sh* to use *Emacs.old.app/Contents/MacOS/Emac*s

However, this is how I set up a Common Lisp environment on my Mac. I am wondering if there are less cumbersome ways.

Comment: Recommending tools is off-topic on stackoverflow. Anyway, you can download Clozure CL from Apple's Mac App Store for free. An excellent, but expensive option is LispWorks.

Comment: **"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."**

Comment: "I am wondering if there are less cumbersome ways."  Most Lisps aren't very hard to install, but getting an IDE for them is a bit more complicated.  LispWorks has a nice IDE and is available in a Personal Edition.  CCL may have a Mac IDE.  I'm not sure, but I think Allegro has an X11-based IDE that you can use on OSX.  For other things (or for those), you can also use SLIME in Emacs.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: CCL has a Mac IDE. It's also extremely simple to install via the Appstore. Allegro CL has a X11/GTK+ based IDE. Then you have a new problem: X11/GTK+ on a Mac...

Comment: @RainerJoswig Thanks for the update.  I remembered that CCL had a (somewhat primitive) IDE in the past, but I haven't used it in a few years, so I didn't want to mention it with certainty.

Comment: IMO, Emacs & Slime makes a very good Lisp IDE. I use [this Emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/), Clozure CL, and [QuickLisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/). Installing and setting up Slime with Quicklisp is very easy. (I'm not sure that even Seibel recommends lispbox any more.)

Answer (score 9):

Here is how to set up an environment with Emacs, SBCL and SLIME from scratch using the latest binaries available at this time.

- Install Emacs from http://emacsformacosx.com (Emacs Version 24.3)
- Install SBCL 1.1.8 from http://www.sbcl.org/platform-table.html in a directory of your choosing (e.g. `~/sbcl/`)

  ```
  $ tar xjvf sbcl-1.1.8-x86-64-darwin-binary.tar.bz2
  $ cd sbcl-1.1.8-x86-64-darwin
  $ INSTALL_ROOT=~/sbcl/ sh install.sh
  ```
- Install Quicklisp from http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/, and then install SLIME using Quicklisp

  ```
  $ curl -O http://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp
  $ SBCL_HOME=~/sbcl/lib/sbcl ~/sbcl/bin/sbcl --load quicklisp.lisp # launch SBCL 
  * (quicklisp-quickstart:install) ; complete Quicklisp installation
  * (ql:quickload "quicklisp-slime-helper") ; install SLIME
  * (ql:add-to-init-file) ; to load Quicklisp every time SBCL is started
  * (quit)
  ```
- Create `~/.emacs` with these lines in it

  ```
  (setenv "SBCL_HOME" (expand-file-name "~/sbcl/lib/sbcl"))
  (setq inferior-lisp-program "~/sbcl/bin/sbcl")
  (load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
  ```
- Launch Emacs and invoke SLIME using `M-x slime`